# How to call a private function via friend function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, googletest

Hello I am trying to access a private member function is `Gtest`. 
The code looks somewhat similar to this. So, how can I access `static void Pri_fun`?

```
using namespace std;
class test{

};
class abc{
public:
    friend class test;
private:
    static void Pri_fun()
        {
        cout << "private fun called \n";
        }
};
int main()
{
    abc ab;
    test *abd;
    abd->Pri_fun();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's a static function, you should access it via the class name:

```
abc::Pri_fun();
```

You should make a caller function though, or call it from the friend class' constructor:

```
class test{
public:
    void foo() 
    {
        abc::Pri_fun();
    }
};
```

or

```
class test{
public:
    test() 
    {
        abc::Pri_fun();
    }
};
```